# Can I get the account details or logged details of an application from the data / file system directory of phone?

Tags: applications, file-system, system, accounts

Can i get the account details or logged details of an application from the data file of the application in the file system. My device is rooted.

For example I have two Instagram accounts saved in the app. Can I get any details about the account from the file system of the application.

Comment: What app you are taking about. Please edit your question and provide the name of the app and a link to the app in Google PlayStore. Are the accounts visible in the accounts list of Android?

Comment: If you are looking for a way to get the account information for the app's data files then that is probably impossible. Apps store confidential user data in files which are not visible to users in their file managers. Also, if one finds such a file, then parsing it to get necessary details is another challenge.